# android radiogroup doesn't uncheck item on selection changed

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I've a very simple layout with a radiogroup with many radiobuttons.

On android Api 16 the very basic mechanics of radiobutton doesnt work. When click at first item it get selected. When click at any other item both items will be selected at same time... if keep doing this at some point all items will have the selection circle at them...

this happens on android 16, but on android 29 the very same code works normal

[image]

```
 this.radioGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.customListRadio);

  AppCompatRadioButton radio = new AppCompatRadioButton(this.getContext());
        radio.setId(R.id.newListButton);
        radio.setText(getString(R.string.new_list));
        this.radioGroup.addView(radio, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.lists.size(); i++)
            addNewRadioButton(this.listNames.get(i), this.lists.get(i).size());


 @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void addNewRadioButton(String name, int size) {

        int index = this.listNames.indexOf(name);

        AppCompatRadioButton newRadio = new AppCompatRadioButton(getContext());
        newRadio.setText(name + " (" + size + ")");
        newRadio.setId(name.hashCode());
        this.radioGroup.addView(newRadio, index);
        registerForContextMenu(newRadio);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `R.id.customListRadio` is RadioGroup object in following line:

```
this.radioGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.customListRadio);
```

if all of your radioButtons are not in same RadioGroup, than they will work individually.